# How to loop this json response in swift with swiftyjson

Tags: swift3

```
{
        "tt8178486": "tt8178486",
        "tt7984766": "tt7984766",
        "tt1950235": "tt1950235"
}
```

I'm trying to for loop this array with swifty json. but not working any of it.

Any support?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [SwiftyJSON Loops](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#loop)?

Comment: It worked. Awesome. :) Thank you so much

Comment: it was mixing the array :( each time I make that string to json it mixing